# PDO - Does PDO prepare query cache now?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, pdo, query-cache

I read lots of articles, but I can't find a certainly clear answer for this question.

Most articles do not seem are recent ones, so I want to check again.

Does MYSQL query cache affect PDO prepared queries now?

If I send this prepare twice

```
$mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ?");
```

the second SELECT will reflect the result by cache?

If YES, and if there is the different page send the same prepare query, does the cache work fine?

I read the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-operation.html) and know the query cache support native SQL query: mysql_stmt_prepare() and mysql_stmt_execute().

But I didn't know how PDO prepare queries working.